# How to download whole web directory with multiple download streams?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I want to download a directory with 100s of large files (500MB - 1.5GB each.) The only problem is there is a download speed limit, and it takes nearly an hour just to download a single file.

What built in command or package on Linux would be able to download all files in a web directory with multiple download streams? If I ever have to restart, I would need the program to ignore already downloaded files.

Answer (score 2):

Read the man page for **wget**. It supports exactly what you want.

Note that most sites will ban you for downloading too many files too quickly.  Someone is paying for that bandwidth, and if you leech too much, it becomes a [tragedy of the commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons).

Comment: I know the basics of wget, but I don't know how to download with multiple streams.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to wget, you can use [axel](http://axel.alioth.debian.org/) to open multiple streams for a single file, in case you need more speed on single files as well.

Comment: "open multiple streams for a single file" Will it download a whole directory full of files?

Comment: Nope. Look for "Recursive Retrieval Options"